Running dialog “Reformat code” some features do not work
With PphStorm 2024.1 when I run  dialog “Reformat code”  some features do not work as I expect :

I expected file declarations at top would be sorted - I have no this :


In  Editor->Code Style->PHP->Code conversion->Sort Use statements = ‘Alphabetically’


Empty lines would be removed in file declarations


I did not find relative options


namespace would be moved to new line, if is located on the same like with php start tag


I did not find relative options

I try to follow psr12 - but with some changes...

Run your code under some tools intended for code fixing. Like PHP CS Fixer




under some tools . Which options have I to check to see these tools are valid ?




CS Fixer is valid and has integration with PHPStorm

I have CS Fixer activate in settings. Are there some options I have to pay attention at ?
